# How to JOIN on different CONCAT expressions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to Join tables based on a `CONCAT` expression containing different text criteria.

I have tried a inefficient method that just takes way too long to query.

```
SELECT 
sf.displayId, 
-- tw.displayText,
CASE
        WHEN tw.DisplayText IN ('N/A', 'NotApplicable', 'Not Applicable')
        THEN 'Not Applicable'
        ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(tw.DisplayText,'client','Client'),'approved','Approved'),'rejected','Rejected'),'review','Review'),'Requirement','Requirement'),'open','Open'),'submitted','Submitted'),'complete','Complete'),'incomplete','Incomplete'),'pending','Pending'),'resubmit','Resubmit'),'Awaiting review','Awaiting Review')
        END AS AuditStatus
FROM Connect.Data.supplier_form sf
JOIN Connect.Data.translation tw 
     ON ((CONCAT('workflowStepName' , sf.workflowStatusId) = tw.translationField) OR (CONCAT('workflowStepMessage' , sf.workflowStatusId) = tw.translationField))
     AND tw.language = 'en'
WHERE sf.deleted = 0
AND tw.displayText IN ('Awaiting Review','Awaiting review')
ORDER BY sf.displayId
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

I want to JOIN `Connect.Data.supplier_form sf` based on the `CONCAT` expression in a far more efficient way.

Comment: You might want to consider adding the `CONCAT` expressions as persisted computed columns in your table `Connect.Data.supplier_form`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how good the SQL optimizer is in SQL Server, so you may try to flip the order of the join condition to make it easier to use an index. I would do two things:

- I would change the `JOIN` condition to:

  ```
  JOIN Connect.Data.translation tw 
  ON tw.language = 'en'
  AND tw.translationField in (
    CONCAT('workflowStepName' , sf.workflowStatusId),
    CONCAT('workflowStepMessage' , sf.workflowStatusId)
  )
  ```
- And I would add the index:

  ```
  create index ix1 on Connect.Data.translation(language, translationField);
  ```

Give it a try and let us know if it improves the performance.